# Custom BeanNameResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'name'

Tags: el

I am trying to run EL 3.0 in standalone mode inside a servlet on Tomcat 8 using the following code -

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.setAttribute("name", "Test1");

    ELProcessor processor = new ELProcessor();
    processor.getELManager().addBeanNameResolver(new BeanNameResolver() {  
    @Override
    public Object getBean(String beanName) {
       return request.getAttribute(beanName);
    }
    }); 

    response.getWriter().write((String)processor.eval("name"));
}
```

Various articles on EL 3.0 mention that in order to resolve a bean it should be first defined using ELProcessor.defineBean(). However with custom bean resolver as defined above it should be able to resolve bean from request. When I run this code on tomcat 8, it shows following error -

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'name'
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:100)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:187)
javax.el.ELProcessor.getValue(ELProcessor.java:45)
javax.el.ELProcessor.eval(ELProcessor.java:38)
org.koyad.servlet.TestELServlet.doGet(TestELServlet.java:59)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standalone javax.el.ELProcessor will throw this exception if it finds an undefined variable name in the expression condition. You can not even write null checks for undefined variables: 
`${empty unknownVariable}`
will throw an exception if this variable hasn't been set before this. If it has been set to `null`, then it will return `true`.

When you are providing a custom BeanNameResolver implementation, you need to override the other methods also. For example the isNameResolved method is used to indicate that your resolver actually solved this value.

I have a custom BeanNameResolver that uses a custom Environment class (basically a map, similar to your request):

```
public static class EnvironmentBeanNameResolver extends BeanNameResolver{

    private Environment environment;

    public EnvironmentBeanNameResolver( Environment environment ){
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNameResolved( String beanName ){
        return environment.containsAttribute( beanName );
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean( String beanName ){
        return environment.getAttribute( beanName );
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanValue( String beanName, Object value ){
        environment.setAttribute( beanName, value );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly( String beanName ){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canCreateBean( String beanName ){
        return true;
    }

}
```

and I use it like this

```
ELProcessor processor = new ELProcessor();
processor.getELManager().addBeanNameResolver( new EnvironmentBeanNameResolver( environment ) );
boolean result = (boolean)processor.eval( "empty knownVariable" );
```